# rewrite rule in .htaccess - regex for persian

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expression

I write a regular expression so that it works when using the term Persian.
 I'm using the following code but the following code does not work.

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That range is for Arabic and this `\uD800[\uDFA0-\uDFDE]` one is for Persian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just match for everything? I'm not sure the `-` character range works the way you're using it:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/(.+?)/?$ test.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```